# Div not taking 100% width with position absolute and old doctype in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Div not taking 100% width with position absolute in IE. It render on quirks mode in IE. There is any way to make div 100% width without changing doctype and without specify width

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div style="width:500px;">
asfdsaf
<div style="background:#ff0000; position:absolute; height:8px; left:0; right:0"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You've got a doctype, so it shouldn't be in quirks mode. Check that the doctype is valid and correct. Also check that there isn't any white space, comments or any other before the it -- the doctype *must* be the very first thing in the document, otherwise IE will ignore it and dump you into quirks mode; even innocent white space like a line feed can cause it to reject it.

Comment: Which IE? Which rendering mode is it in? You speak off width 100% but don't set it. Instead you have set `left` and `right` at the same time which older IEs (can recall which right now).

Comment: ... don't support. (Lost the end of my sentence there somehow).